# Alternative to Bendy Bones for gltf/glb export

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, gltf, three.js

I'm trying to export the following rig to use in three.js:
[image]

The goal is to have it move on two axis like this:

[image]

As you can see, the Base cube is connected to the upper part of the mesh via a tube, which is rigged with a bendy bone, that is a child of the upper part of the mesh. This sollution works fine in Blender but the problem is, that gltf doesn't support bendy bones, so I'm looking for a simple alternative. The goal is to use the model in a three.js application.

Comment: maybe create a chain of bones and give an IK constraint to the top one?

Comment: @moonboots I'm actually not sure if three.js supports IK rigs

Comment: if this is for pre-made animation, there's an Auto IK option that allows you to animate as if the bone had IK, or you can bake the animation

Comment: @moonboots unfortunately it isn't for a pre-made animation, in that case I'd just bake it. It is for a web application where the user should be able to rotate the mesh along the two axis

Comment: three.js can be used with IK rigs (see https://github.com/jsantell/THREE.IK), but I don't think there's any off-the-shelf workflow to export an IK rig from Blender to three.js. You'd need to set the IK rig up again in three.js.